# Speech recognizing in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a speech recognition code which takes voice from the microphone and process till a "Stop" is said. The code works for the first voice but then it gives an error. The code which I wrote is below:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
r = sr.Recognizer()


with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    while True:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        print("You said " + r.recognize(audio)) 
        if r.recognize(audio)=="Facebook":
            webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com')
        if r.recognize(audio)=="Google":
            webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.uk')
        if r.recognize(audio)=="Stop":
            break
```

The error which I am getting is :

```
You said Facebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Work/Scripts/SpeechRecognition/Speech.py", line 9, in <module>
print("You said " + r.recognize(audio)) # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data
File "C:\Users\roradhak.NDS-UK\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 324, in recognize
raise LookupError("Speech is unintelligible")
```

LookupError: Speech is unintelligible

```
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Peter.. I said Facebook and it opened the facebook page. I tried by waiting / No Waiting to say google but the error happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the exception:

```
def recognize(audio):
    try:
        return r.recognize(audio)
    except LookupError, e:
        print e
        return ''
```

Then:

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    while True:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        words = recognize(audio)
        print("You said " + words) 
        if words == "Facebook":
            webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com')
        elif words =="Google":
            webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.uk')
        elif words == "Stop":
            break
```

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Thanks a lot. I have few more on the same but will raise a new question.

Comment: Peter.. I have a problem here. Saying "Stop" won't quit the program.

Comment: What does it print? Does it say `You said Stop` exactly, or something slightly different? e.g. case difference.

Comment: Yes, it prints stop only.
See the output below

    **C:\Python27\python.exe         C:/Work/Scripts/SpeechRecognition/Speech2.py
    You said stop
    Speech is unintelligible
     You said 
     Speech is unintelligible
     You said**

Comment: Peter... I corrected it. Changing from "Stop" to "stop" worked.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem might be that you call `recognize` many times on the same input and the first call has already consumed the audio. You can introduce one extra variable + add try/catch to handle the LookupError.

```
with sr.Microphone() as source:                
    while True:
        audio = r.listen(source)
        try:
            result = r.recognize(audio)
            print("You said " + result)
            words = result.lower()
            if words=="facebook":
                webbrowser.open('https://www.facebook.com')
            if words=="google":
                webbrowser.open('https://www.google.co.uk')
            if words=="stop":
                break
        except LookupError:
            print("Please, speak more clearly")
```

Comment: Asha.. Saying 'Stop' wont quit the program. How can i achieve that

Comment: Corrected by changing "Stop" to "stop"

Comment: Good luck. To not depend on the case, you can convert the recognized strings to lowercase (see updated answer).

Comment: Asha.. Can you please help me to get an answer for the question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938711/how-can-i-make-the-python-to-wait-till-i-complete-speaking